# How can I get the PlayerObject for each connected client in Unity's Netcode for networking?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, multiplayer

I'm new to Unity's Netcode for GameObjects and try to have a simple game, where multiple players connect to a lobby and shoot monsters that are trying to run towards the players.

I'm currenty stuck on the task to identify the nearest player for each monster to run to.

My plan was as follows:

- Let the server control the monsters
- Interate over `NetworkManager.Singleton.ConnectedClientsList`
- Access the `PlayerObject` for each connected client
- Calculate distance between all PlayerObject positions and each monster
- Determine the neares player for each monster

**The problem:**
`ConnectedClientList` returns each connected client, but their `PlayerObject` is `null`:

```
NetworkManager.Singleton.ConnectedClientsList[0]
{Unity.Netcode.NetworkClient}
    ClientId: 0
    OwnedObjects: Count = 0
    PlayerObject: null
NetworkManager.Singleton.ConnectedClientsList[1]
{Unity.Netcode.NetworkClient}
    ClientId: 1
    OwnedObjects: Count = 0
    PlayerObject: null
```

Here is the code for my `MonsterController`:

```
public class MonsterController : NetworkBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private float speed = 10.0f;

    void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    public override void OnNetworkSpawn()
    {
        if (!IsServer) enabled = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        RecalculateNearestPlayerServerRpc();
        var dir = nearestPlayer.transform.position - transform.position;
        rb.velocity = dir * speed;
    }


    [ServerRpc]
    private void RecalculateNearestPlayerServerRpc()
    {
        float nearestPlayerDistance = float.MaxValue;
        foreach (NetworkClient client in NetworkManager.Singleton.ConnectedClientsList)
        {
            float sqrDistance = (client.PlayerObject.transform.position-transform.position).sqrMagnitude;

            if (sqrDistance < nearestPlayerDistance)
            {
                nearestPlayerDistance = sqrDistance;
                nearestPlayer = client.PlayerObject;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I spawn and give ownership like this:

```
public class GameManager : NetworkBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private PlayerController _playerPrefab;

    public override void OnNetworkSpawn() {
        SpawnPlayerServerRpc(NetworkManager.Singleton.LocalClientId);
    }   

    [ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
    private void SpawnPlayerServerRpc(ulong playerId) {
        var spawn = Instantiate(_playerPrefab);
        spawn.NetworkObject.SpawnWithOwnership(playerId);
    }

    public override void OnDestroy() {
        base.OnDestroy();
        MatchmakingService.LeaveLobby();
        if(NetworkManager.Singleton != null )NetworkManager.Singleton.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

Am I missing something or is this not the right way to do it?

Comment: Do you spawn the player objects manually or are you using the Netcode PlayerPrefab?

Answer (score 0):

If someone finds this. You can instantiate them like normal on the server and then call SpawnAsPlayerObject(clientId); So like this:

```
[ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
private void SpawnPlayerServerRpc(ulong playerId) {
    var spawn = Instantiate(_playerPrefab);
    spawn.NetworkObject.SpawnAsPlayerObject(playerId);
}
```